# Make part of a border invisible ? CSS

Tags: javascript, css, sass, nuxt.js

I've been struggling to reproduce this button :

[image: button with round border which becomes transparent around the check icon]

Specifically I can't seem to find how to make the border invisible around the check icon. At the moment it's "finished" except for this part.

It's a nuxt3 component and it looks like this :

```js
 <template>
  <div class="button-container">
    <nuxt-link :to="link.link">
      {{ link.title }}
    </nuxt-link>
    <div class="check-container">
      <svg-icon type="mdi" :path="mdiCheckBold" class="icon is-large" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { defineProps } from 'vue'
import SvgIcon from '@jamescoyle/vue-icon'
import { mdiCheckBold } from '@mdi/js'

type Link = {
  title: string;
  link: string;
};

interface Props {
  link: Link;
}

defineProps<Props>()
</script>

<style scoped lang="scss">
@import 'assets/style/_variables.scss';

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  border: dotted $white 0.24rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 18rem;
  height: 18rem;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: $white;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .check-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 11.5rem;
    left: 11.5rem;
    border: solid $white 0.24rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 7rem;
    height: 7rem;
    color: $white;
    background: $background-gradient;
  }
}
</style>
```

Any help would be great, thank you in advance !

Comment: Essentially you can't. A border isn't "breakable" that way.  Consider an SVG instead?

Comment: Thanks ! It'll be the first svg I'll create from scratch, wish me luck !

Answer (score 1):

You can use mask to cut part of the border:

```css
.box {
  --a: 40deg; /* the position */
  --r: 35px; /* the radius */

  width: 200px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px dashed red;
  -webkit-mask:
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at
       calc(50% + 50%*cos(var(--a)))
       calc(50% + 50%*sin(var(--a))),
      #0000 98%,#000)
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

An idea of the full code:

```css
button {
  --a: 40deg; /* the position */
  --r: 35px; /* the radius */

  font-size: 20px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}
button:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 3px dashed;
  -webkit-mask:
     radial-gradient(var(--r) at
       calc(50% + 50%*cos(var(--a)))
       calc(50% + 50%*sin(var(--a))),
      #0000 98%,#000)
}
button:after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: inherit;
  inset: calc(50% - var(--r) + 10px); /* adjust the 10px to control the gap */
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/200) center/cover; /* place your SVG icon here */
  /* adjust the 70px based on your real use case */
  transform: rotate(var(--a)) translate(70px) rotate(calc(-1*var(--a)))
}


body {
 background: linear-gradient(90deg,blue,pink);
}
```

```html
<button class="box">Commencer</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution to render an halo around the `.check-container` element, that will hide anything behind (see the parent element border) could be using `box-shadow`

```css
:root{
  --border-color: white;
  --link-color: white;
  --check-color: white;
  --check-border: white;
  --check-bg: aqua;
  --parent-bg: aqua;
}

body{
  background: var(--parent-bg);
}

.button-container {
  position: relative;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
    
  border: dotted var(--border-color) 0.24rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  width: 18rem;
  height: 18rem;
  
  background: var(--parent-bg);
}

.button-container a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--link-color);
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.button-container .check-container {
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 11.5rem;
  left: 11.5rem;
  
  border: solid var(--check-border) 0.24rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  
  width: 7rem;
  height: 7rem;
  
  color: var(--check-color);
  background: var(--check-bg);
     
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1em var(--parent-bg);  
}


.icon-circle {    
    font-size: 5em;    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

<div class="button-container">
  <a href="">COMMENCER</a>      
  <div class="check-container">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-check icon-circle"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want simple and rookie solution , use other  over it , add different z-index to both elements and adjust  position as per your need .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).